# Is it possible to extract a string in presenter class without context?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-mvp

I am looking into extracting a string in a presenter class. There's a way to do it with context but it's not recommended to use context in presenter due to memory leaks and other issues. Is there a way I can do it without using context?
Here's my code for example :

```
       testLine = when {
        sourceIds.isEmpty() -> ""
        sourceIds.size > 1 -> String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d test", sourceIds.size)
        else -> String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s", newMembers?.getNameForId(sourceIds[0]))
    }
```

Comment: not really familiar with mvp, but is there no way for you to pass in the values you would have gotten with context, from a class which has context ? then this method just decides which value to use, but isn't responsible for getting them with context. i'm assuming that your view class will have context, can you not pass it from there to this presenter ?

Comment: She can pass it, but she shouldn't. Best approach would be to get string in view and pass it to presenter to manipulate it. If you can't figure it out post more of your code where you call presenter from view and what you do after in presenter

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to drop context explicitly for example

Presenter

```
private var mContext : Context? = null

fun takeContext( context : Context ){
    this.mContext = context
}

fun dropContext(){
    this.mContext = null
}
```

calling above from

`takeContext` -> `onViewCreated`,
`dropContext` -> `onDestroyView`

So that your context is only available when your view is drawed.